# Laravel morphedByMany analogue for morphedByOne

Tags: php, laravel

I have a relation on post model:

```
public function partners() {
     return $this->morphedByMany('App\Partner', 'postable');
}
```

And I have a separate table postables.

I need get only one partner. In blade I can do this:

```
$post->partners->first()->title
```

This is working. But is there analogue for morphedByOne? I want return only one collection, but not array of collections..

Comment: Are you referring that you need a [One-to-One relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations)? Or do you just want the same relation by get a single model response without using `first()`?

Comment: @Bogdan One to One relationship working only with columns in one table. I have a separate table, I need relation for separate table.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean you will always only need the first `partner` from the `partners` relationship?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I have table partners, posts and postables. Postables - is polymorphic table. In laravel docs I finded only morphedByMany relation, morphedByOne relation I did not find.

Comment: Which version of laravel do you use? From 5.7 docs you can use morphOne
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

Comment: @ApródIllés please see table structure for morphOne!!!!! This is not for separatate polymorphic table!!!

Comment: @Dronax I think your postable table is equivalent with images table in laravel docs. If not, then please provide your table structure more detailed!